# Betareg Half-Normal Plot "Error in chol.default(K)"

Tags: residuals, qq-plot, beta-regression

I am running into a very odd problem when calling plot.betareg (betareg package in R) to produce half normal plots: Sometimes I receive a plot, sometimes I get for the same model with the same data an error message. Here some "proof" from my console.

```
> plot(model2, which = 5, type = "sweighted2", nsim = 200)
Error in chol.default(K) : 
  the leading minor of order 17 is not positive definite
Error in chol.default(K) : 
  the leading minor of order 17 is not positive definite
> plot(model2, which = 5, type = "sweighted2", nsim = 20)
> plot(model2, which = 5, type = "sweighted2", nsim = 200)
>
```

As you see, first model2 (which was working last week) does gives me an error message, then after changing the number of simulations (nsim) back and forth the same model works.
I started playing around with nsim because I suspected that the error is related to the simulations run to produce the plot. However, there is also no pattern on how modifying nsim helps: sometimes setting a higher number resolves the error, sometimes a smaller number does so, other times it does not change the situation at all - and without changing anything the model will plot again.
**How should I interpret this error/what are its implications?

How could I fix it? (So the analysis is reliably reproducible.)**

I cannot share the data, but hope this background information helps understanding the problem better: Its a dataset of a social science experiment with roughly 800 participants. There are NAs for some of the variables for some individuals. (I only cleaned the dataset regarding variables which have a poly term in the regression.) The problems described above occur in a model that roughly looks like this:

```
test.model <- betareg(y ~ group + female + edu + age + dummy1 + poly(likert_response1, 2) + dummy2 + likert_response2 + factor1 + likert_response3 + likert_response4 | group + female + group*edu + group*poly(age,2) + group*dummy1 + poly(likert_response1, 2) + group*dummy2 + likert_response2 + factor1 + likert_response3 + poly(likert_response4, 3), data = test.data)
```

Here is a set of 100 simulated obs of data that resembles my dataset.

```
"","group","female","age","edu","dummy1","likert1","dummy2","likert2","factor1","likert3","likert4","y"
"1","1","1",34,"2","1",3,"1",2,"0",3,4,0.74
"2","2","0",27,"1","1",6,"1",4,"0",6,6,0.77
"3","2","1",18,"0","0",4,"0",4,"0",4,4,0.64
"4","2","0",47,"2","1",5,"1",3,"0",5,6,0.81
"5","1","1",49,"1","1",6,"0",4,"-1",4,4,0.8
"6","3","1",43,"2","1",4,"0",4,"0",4,4,0.85
"7","3","1",60,"2","1",5,"0",3,"0",5,5,0.81
"8","1","1",50,"2","1",5,"1",4,"0",5,4,0.72
"9","1","0",19,"0","0",6,"1",2,"1",6,6,0.69
"10","1","0",23,"2","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,6,0.74
"11","1","1",48,"1","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.77
"12","1","0",55,"1","1",5,"0",2,"0",5,6,0.71
"13","2","0",56,"1","1",5,"0",2,"0",6,6,0.73
"14","2","1",30,"2","1",5,"1",4,"0",6,6,0.8
"15","2","1",54,"1","1",4,"0",3,"1",4,5,0.78
"16","2","1",54,"0","1",6,"1",6,"0",5,6,0.74
"17","1","1",54,"1","1",4,"0",3,"0",3,4,0.75
"18","1","0",23,"2","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,6,0.74
"19","3","1",69,"1","1",5,"0",2,"0",4,3,0.77
"20","3","0",63,"1","1",3,"1",4,"0",5,6,0.83
"21","2","1",47,"2","1",5,"0",5,"0",6,5,0.76
"22","1","1",34,"2","1",3,"1",2,"0",3,4,0.74
"23","2","1",70,"1","1",5,"0",2,"0",3,3,0.61
"24","2","1",51,"0","1",5,"0",3,"0",6,6,0.6
"25","2","1",51,"0","1",5,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.62
"26","2","0",64,"0","1",3,"0",4,"0",4,4,0.62
"27","1","0",51,"2","1",5,"0",4,"1",5,6,0.85
"28","3","0",80,"0","1",5,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.86
"29","3","0",57,NA,"1",4,"0",1,"0",3,3,0.79
"30","2","1",27,"0","1",4,"0",4,"-1",5,6,0.62
"31","3","0",20,NA,"0",6,"1",4,"0",5,6,0.85
"32","1","0",63,"1","1",4,"0",3,"0",5,5,0.74
"33","1","0",75,"1","1",4,"0",4,"0",3,4,0.64
"34","3","1",29,"2","1",3,"0",4,"0",3,4,0.82
"35","1","0",76,"2","1",6,"0",4,"0",5,5,0.75
"36","3","0",40,"0","1",5,"1",1,"1",2,1,0.8
"37","1","0",55,"1","1",5,"0",2,"0",5,6,0.71
"38","3","1",53,"2","1",3,"0",3,"0",4,4,0.74
"39","2","1",54,"1","1",4,"0",3,"1",4,5,0.78
"40","2","1",27,"2","1",4,"0",2,"0",5,4,0.72
"41","2","1",56,"0","1",5,"0",4,"0",5,5,0.81
"42","3","0",29,"0","1",5,"0",1,"0",5,5,0.78
"43","3","1",26,"2","1",6,"0",3,"0",6,6,0.87
"44","1","1",45,"1","1",4,"0",4,"0",5,6,0.81
"45","3","1",54,"1","1",5,"0",4,"1",6,6,0.8
"46","1","0",39,"1","1",6,"0",4,"0",6,6,0.76
"47","3","0",57,NA,"1",4,"0",1,"0",3,3,0.79
"48","2","0",47,"2","1",5,"1",3,"0",5,6,0.81
"49","1","0",37,"0","1",5,"0",2,"0",5,6,0.83
"50","1","0",21,"0","0",4,"1",3,"0",4,4,0.66
"51","2","0",48,"2","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,6,0.63
"52","3","0",50,"2","1",5,"1",4,"0",NA,6,0.77
"53","3","1",65,"0","1",6,"1",1,"1",NA,6,0.72
"54","3","0",24,"2","1",4,"0",3,"0",5,6,0.84
"55","3","0",60,"2","1",6,"1",5,"-1",NA,6,0.83
"56","3","0",52,"2","1",5,"0",3,"0",6,6,0.82
"57","2","0",54,"2","1",1,"0",3,"0",1,1,0.36
"58","2","1",36,"0","1",3,"0",3,"0",5,6,0.72
"59","3","1",47,"0","1",5,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.85
"60","3","0",37,"2","1",3,"0",NA,"-1",4,4,0.71
"61","2","0",76,"1","1",6,"0",2,"0",5,4,0.74
"62","3","0",73,"2","1",6,"1",1,"0",6,6,0.76
"63","2","1",51,"0","1",5,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.62
"64","1","1",65,"0","1",5,"0",4,"-1",5,5,0.59
"65","2","1",72,"1","1",3,"0",3,"-1",3,3,0.6
"66","2","0",33,"1","1",4,"0",4,"0",4,4,0.65
"67","2","0",29,"2","1",2,"0",1,"0",5,5,0.56
"68","2","0",48,"2","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,6,0.63
"69","3","1",79,"0","1",5,"0",5,"-1",6,6,0.67
"70","1","1",25,"2","1",4,"0",3,"0",6,5,0.62
"71","2","0",64,"1","1",6,"0",4,"0",6,6,0.69
"72","3","0",60,"2","1",5,"0",2,"0",6,6,0.87
"73","1","0",58,"1","1",2,"1",4,"0",3,5,0.79
"74","2","1",32,"2","1",5,"1",2,"0",5,4,0.7
"75","2","0",32,"2","1",4,"0",4,"0",5,4,0.8
"76","3","1",54,"1","1",6,"1",2,"0",6,6,0.91
"77","3","1",76,"1","1",3,"0",5,"-1",5,5,0.8
"78","1","0",36,"2","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.73
"79","2","0",60,"2","1",5,"0",5,"0",6,6,0.63
"80","1","0",72,"0","1",6,"0",1,"1",1,1,0.7
"81","2","1",57,"2","1",5,"0",2,"0",NA,3,0.61
"82","1","1",52,"2","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.52
"83","2","0",73,"1","1",6,"0",2,"0",6,6,0.79
"84","2","0",76,"2","1",5,"1",5,"1",5,6,0.77
"85","1","1",48,"1","1",6,"0",5,"0",5,5,0.77
"86","3","0",60,"2","1",5,"0",2,"0",6,6,0.87
"87","3","0",58,"1","1",6,"1",2,"1",5,5,0.78
"88","3","0",61,"2","1",6,"1",4,"1",5,5,0.82
"89","3","1",62,"1","1",4,"0",6,"-1",4,4,0.8
"90","1","1",70,"1","1",6,"0",2,"1",4,6,0.82
"91","1","1",29,"0","1",4,"1",3,"0",4,4,0.74
"92","1","1",18,"1","0",4,"0",2,"1",5,5,0.59
"93","3","1",65,"0","1",6,"1",1,"1",NA,6,0.72
"94","3","0",46,"2","1",4,"0",4,"0",4,4,0.73
"95","3","1",50,"2","1",4,"0",2,NA,4,2,0.8
"96","3","1",61,"1","1",3,"0",2,"-1",NA,1,0.82
"97","3","1",29,"2","1",3,"0",4,"0",3,4,0.82
"98","3","0",20,NA,"0",6,"1",4,"0",5,6,0.85
"99","2","0",32,"2","1",4,"0",4,"0",5,4,0.8
"100","2","1",66,"1","1",6,"0",3,"0",6,5,0.82
```

Comment: Hard to say what exactly happens without a reproducible example. The source of the problem is likely that the `sweighted2` residuals require computation of an n x n matrix which can become unstable. And the reason that this only occurs sometimes is that the halfnormal plot generates random variations of the data, refits the model, and recomputes the residuals. So apparently the problem only occurs in certain random subsamples.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I can not follow completely.What does it mean that thte n x x becomes "unstable". Based on the second part of your comment I might add that there are some NAs in the data - could the reason be that those cases are randomly selected and then produce the error?  (I cannot share the data, but added some specification to the question)

Comment: Even if you cannot share the data, you can create a minimal working example using e.g. simulated data that loosely resembles yours, or an excerpt. Right now troubleshooting is a shot in the dark.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I hope adding the simulated data helps finding a solution. Please let me know, if I can improve my answer otherwise. I am rather new to statistics and this page. I apologise for resulting inconvenience.